# adding the crawled links into the set in python

Tags: python, web-crawler

i need to add the crawled links to set but it's giving me error how fix this thanks for any help

```
     #from here i am getting the error 
     soup = BeautifulSoup(self.urls.read(),'lxml')

     for urls in soup.find_all('a'):
        self.links = urls.get('href')
     for rm_duplicate in level: # level is set contain list of url 
         try:
          if rm_duplicate!=url and rm_duplicate!=url+str('/'):
           if re.match('http://www.url..*',rm_duplicate):
            self.hugelink.add(rm_duplicate)

         except:
             print('handling')
```